# Leak instance of Scanner class in Java using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner, instance-variables, resource-leak

I am new to Java. Can anyone tell me how to remove this resource leak error? The error says the resource leak is never closed.

[image: resource leak]

Comment: You have to close the resources when you are using in java else there will be a leak in your application which causes OOM. call leak.close() in finally or use try with resources in java which will do it for you.

Comment: Yes... it worked fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Java 7+ version you can use try with resources like the below.

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.println("Enter a number - ");
            int n = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("N is " + n);
        }
    }
```